# biblatex philosophy origyear bug

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

The biblatex-philosophy (modern/classic/verbose) versions gives the wrong introductory string (i.e., "trans.") with the origyear field. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test2.bib}

@book{angut,  
    shorthand = {AN},  
    title = {Anguttara-Nikaya},  
    editor = {Richard Morris and Warder, A. K.},  
    volumes = {6},  
    origyear = 1885,  
    origendyear = 1910,  
    year = 1958,  
    endyear = 1976,  
    address = {London},  
    publisher = {The Pali Text Society},  
    keywords = {abbre,pali}  
}  

\end{filecontents}  

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=philosophy-modern,   language=american,publocformat=loccolonpub]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test2.bib}  

\begin{document}  

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The documentation says that using the `orig*` fields is deprecated.

Comment: @egreg Yeah, you are right. But does it mean that I need to define a new related entry in the bib file? Isn't there a workaround for it?

Comment: AFAIK `endyear`/`origendyear` are non-standard and work only accidentally. Use the `date`/`origdate` fields with proper date ranges instead: `date = {1958/1976}, origdate = {1885/1910},`. This has no bearing on the issue, though, I will have a look at that in a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `orig*` fields are deprecated in `biblatex-philosophy`, you should use the `related` functionality instead. (Note that the standard `bibiatex` styles simply ignore the `orig*` fields, so that behaviour is nothing out of the ordinary.)

The `biblatex-philosophy` documentation states

> The following [`orig*`] fields can hold the translation or the original edition data. They are preceded by the string “trans.” or “orig. ed.”, respectively according to the `origfields=trans` (default) or
>   `origfields=origed` option (see below). Note that the `origdate`/`transdate` field is needed in order to print these fields.

That means that by default it is assumed that `orig*` refers to a translation, you can change that with the `origfields=origed` option. This will leave you with

> Anguttara-Nikaya, 6 vols., London: The Pali Text Society; orig. pub. as 1885-1910.

which is sub-par due to the missing title.

You can use

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{angut,  
    shorthand = {AN},  
    title = {Anguttara-Nikaya},  
    editor = {Richard Morris and Warder, A. K.},  
    volumes = {6},  
    date = {1958/1976},
    origdate = {1885/1910},
    address = {London},  
    publisher = {The Pali Text Society},  
}  

\end{filecontents}  

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=philosophy-modern,   language=american,publocformat=loccolonpub, origfields=origed]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}  

\NewBibliographyString{origpubbare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{origpubbare  = {orig\adddotspace pub\adddotspace}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{transorigstring}{%
  \iffieldundef{reprinttitle}%
  {\printtext{\ifdefstring{\bbx@origfields}{origed}
      {\bibstring{origpubbare}}%
      {\bibstring{translationas}}}\nopunct}%
  {\printtext{\bibstring{reprint}}}\nopunct}
\makeatother

\begin{document}  

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

instead.

That way we only write 'orig. pub.' instead of 'orig. pub. as'.

Comment: How about:  \DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{origpubas = {orig. pub.}}  This is admittedly a hack, but it seems to work.

Comment: @ashinpan You could also do `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{origpubas = {orig\adddotspace pub\adddotspace}}`, but I didn't want to advocate this as is takes the 'as' away from the string when the name clearly indicates it should be there.

Comment: This is why this is a hack, isn't it? :D